# jQuery event can't trigger when the target position changed

Tags: jquery

I met a weird issue when using jQuery event, here is thing:

There is a form needed to be validated, so we add a `blur` event listener on the form for all inputs, when an input lost focus, the listener will validate if user input is valid, if not, an error message will appear under input, thus push later HTML elements down. And we also bind `click` event for a button to submit the form.

When you finished input in one of input area, then directly click the submit button. The expected result is: check if user input is valid, if so, trigger the click event of submit button. The real result is: the `blur` event of input will be triggered, but the `click` event won't be triggered whenever user input is valid.

I tried in jsfiddle, and found that in normal case, the blur event and click event will both triggered in turn. But what happened here is that: in the `blur` event handler, we changed the page layout, the position of submit button is changed, thus caused the `click` not triggered.

Is this a bug of jQuery? Does any body run into this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

See example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuuuuc/SYQL7/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is not a bug. `focusout` is being triggered before `click` because `click` is not `one-state` event. It has 2 states : `mousedown` and `mouseup`. You should'nt have done such a layout in a `form` but if you really wanna do this you can use some extra checking with `mousedown` like

```
var mouse_down = false;
$(function(){
  $('#in').on('focusout',function(e){
    console.log('focus event: %o',e);
    if (mouse_down) {
        mouse_down = false;
        $('#button').click();
    }
    $('#test').css({'margin-bottom':'100px'});
  });
  $('#button').on('click',function(e){
    console.log('click event: %o',e);
  });
  $('#button').on('mousedown',function(e){
    mouse_down = true;
  });
  $(document).on('mouseup',function(e){
    mouse_down = false;
  });
})
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SYQL7/4/)

Comment: Thanks @Batu, Our requirement is : when the user input is not valid, show the error message under input, thus changed the position of submit button. When user correct the input and click the submit button directly, this will lead to this layout. Your method will work out, thanks.